# Adding "random number entropy" for GPG keys?

Tags: linux, gpg, random

In the following video: [*Linux HOWTO: Secure Your Data with PGP, Part 2*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQYwqzS-Wyo), you are shown how to create a key pair with `gpg`. At about `1:50`, the instructor says the following:

> While the key is being generated, it is a good idea to **move your mouse around** a little bit to give it a bit more random number entropy for the creation of the keypair.

This seems to me like a myth, especially since command-line tools shouldn't usually be affected by the cursor. On the other hand, I have no clue how Linux's random number generator works, whether it is shared by the GUI or independent from it. Is there any stock in what he claims, or this an example of [cargo cult programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cargo-cult-programming.html)?

Comment: As a side-question, is this the correct use of "urban myth" or is there a similar phrase for "myth within computing"?

Comment: I think the phrase is *urban legend*; I've never heard of *urban myth*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_legend In computing, the phrase ["cargo cult"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cargo-cult-programming.html) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a grain of truth to this, in fact more truth than myth, but nonetheless the statement reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on. Yes, moving the mouse while generating a key with GPG can be a good idea. Yes, moving the mouse contributes some entropy that makes random numbers random. No, moving the mouse does not make the key more secure.

All good random generators suitable for cryptography, and Linux's is in that category, have two components:

- An [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(order_and_disorder)) source, which is non-deterministic. The purpose of the entropy is to bootstrap the random number generator with unpredictable data. The entropy source must be non-deterministic: otherwise, an adversary could reproduce the same computation.
- A [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which produces unpredictable random numbers in a deterministic fashion from a changing internal state.

Entropy has to come from a source that is external to the computer. The user is one source of entropy. What the user does is mostly not random, but the fine timing of keystrokes and mouse movements is so unpredictable as to be slightly random — not very random, but little by little, it accumulates. Other potential sources of entropy include the timing of network packets and camera or microphone white noise. Different kernel versions and configurations may use a different set of sources. Some computers have dedicated hardware RNG circuits based on radioactive decay or, less impressively, unstable electronic circuits. These dedicated sources are especially useful in embedded devices and servers which can have pretty predictable behavior on their first boot, without a user to do weird things.

Linux provides random numbers to programs via two devices: [`/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random). Reading from either device returns cryptographic-quality. Both devices use the same internal RNG state and the same algorithm to transform the state and produce random bytes. They have peculiar limitations which makes neither of them the right thing:

- `/dev/urandom` can return predictable data if the system has not yet accumulated sufficient entropy.
- `/dev/random` calculates the amount of available entropy and blocks if there isn't enough. This sounds good, except that the calculation is based on theoretical considerations that make the amount of available entropy decrease linearly with each output bit. Thus `/dev/random` tends to block very quickly.

Linux systems save the internal RNG state to disk and restore it at boot time. Therefore entropy carries over from one boot to the next. The only time when a Linux system may lack entropy is when it's freshly installed. Once there is sufficient entropy in the system, entropy does not decrease; only Linux's flawed calculation decreases. For more explanations of this consideration, read [`/dev/urandom` is suitable to generate a cryptographic key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939), by a professional cryptographer. See aso [Can you explain the entropy estimate used in random.c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/can-you-explain-the-entropy-estimate-used-in-random-c).

Moving the mouse adds more entropy to the system. But [gpg can only read from `/dev/random`, not `/dev/urandom`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119967/rsa-2048-keypair-generation-via-openssl-0-5s-via-gpg-30s-why-the-difference) (a way to solve this problem is to make `/dev/random` the same 1:9 device as `/dev/urandom`), so it is never at risk of receiving not-random-enough random numbers. **If you don't move the mouse, the key is as random as can be; but what can happen is that gpg may get blocked** in a read from `/dev/random`, waiting for the kernel's entropy counter to rise.

Comment: Except current versions of linux do not, at least from my testing, use input devices as a source of entropy (or at least of estimated entropy). I'm pretty sure they changed that because in theory they could be under an attacker's control.

Comment: @derobert As of 3.12 there's a call to `add_input_randomness` in `drivers/input/input.c`, but I don't know in what circumstances it will actually inject entropy.

Comment: I'm guessing it adds entropy, but with an estimate of 0... I tried both a USB mouse and PS/2 keyboard, neither seemd to up the entropy estimate. Not sure why, though, as I see the call to credit_entropy_bits in the code.

Answer (score 3):

GPG is using the Linux (kernel) random number generator. The kernel generator gets entropy (randomness) from all kinds of places, among them is interrupt timing, for certain interrupts. Moving the mouse (and typing, disk activity, etc.) will all generate interrupts.

So, moving the mouse does indeed potentially feed into the random number generator. But whether it does depends on the exact kernel version in use; newer versions do not (at least in my testing) use keyboard or mouse interrupts for entropy. Disk activity, however, does (so, e.g., running `sync` will add a potentially large amount of entropy, depending on how much is flushed).

In short: this is not true on current Linux versions. It was on older ones.

However, if the generator runs out of entropy, it's supposed to just stop—so your key generation will hang until some entropy is generated. So it'd be a taking-forever problem, not a security problem.

You can see how much entropy is available by `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

Comment: Also note you can use tools like `rngd` to artifically feed the entropy pool.

Comment: @Patrick indeed, and if you have a new chip and trust the NSA (oh, wait, I mean, Intel) you could use RDRAND.

Comment: `haveged` it is another good tool to artificially feed entropy pool.

Comment: That's not the complete story — the RNG doesn't run out of entropy, it runs out of its internal measure of entropy. Also, an important piece of the puzzle is that gpg doesn't care about the mouse, it's the kernel that does.

Comment: @Gilles I've clarified that gpg is using the Linux RNG. And bugs in the entropy estimator seem beyond the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Tails has a extremely fast key generation because it has `haveged` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install haveged
```